# Why is the value of style.visibility blank?

Tags: javascript

a is a loop constant and point is a class name,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("point")[a].style.top;
```

if equated to a variable, the variable will have a value

but why does

```
document.getElementsByClassName("point")[a].style.visibility;
```

result to a blank value?

Comment: Adding complete JS code and HTML will help. Live demo will be very helpful to find problem/solution quickly.

Answer (score 2):

There won't be a value unless you've set it before in Javascript or with inline styles. Just because the browser defaults the css visibility to visible doesn't mean that the Javascript will return "visible"