# Changing element visibility through JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm Trying to create a minimize button for an html element through JavaScript, and the visibility status fails to change [This link sort of explained it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633582/why-is-the-value-of-style-visibility-blank), but the value of visibility does not change.

```js
document.getElementById("inven").style.visibility = "visible"
      
      document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener(
      "click",
      function () {
        console.log("click")
        let inven = document.getElementById("inven");
        console.log(document.getElementById("inven").style.visibility)
        if(inven.style.visibility == "hidden"){
          inven.style.display = "visible"
        }
        if(inven.style.visibility == "visible"){
          inven.style.display = "hidden"
        }
      }
    );
```

```css
  
      #inven {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #242424;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      
      #btn {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: visible;
        top: 500px;
        left: 20px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #cac4c4;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="inven">hi</div>
    <div id="btn">-</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code:

```
if(inven.style.visibility == "hidden"){
  inven.style.display = "visible"
}
```

If the [`visiblity][1]` is `hidden`, you are changing [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property, is it really what you want?

And, you have this:

```
if(inven.style.visibility == "hidden"){
  inven.style.display = "visible"
}
if(inven.style.visibility == "visible"){
  inven.style.display = "hidden"
}
```

If it's `hidden` you'll make it `visible`, which will make the next condition truthy, so it will make it `hidden` again.

Are you looking for something like:

```js
document.getElementById("inven").style.visibility = "visible"

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    console.log("click")
    let inven = document.getElementById("inven");

    console.log(inven.style.visibility)
    if (inven.style.visibility == "hidden") {
      inven.style.visibility = "visible"
    } else {
      inven.style.visibility = "hidden"
    }
  }
);
```

```css
#inven {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #242424;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 500px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #cac4c4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="inven">hi</div>
<div id="btn">-</div>
```